# Location of battery animation file on a Chinese tablet

Tags: automation, power-on

I'm working with a Chinese tablet. I need to turn on the tablet when it is attached to an external power source.

I'm looking for the equivalent file of `playlpm` that you usually find on Samsung devices.

Are there any names for Chinese brands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent battery animation file in most Chinese Android Tablets is called `ipod`.

Replacing its content to `/system/bin/reboot` "partially" works. If I connect the NTC from the battery into the ground pin, it will try to reboot, fail and display the battery animation file.

But if I just attach NTC to the ground, and *remove it when the backlight starts*, it will reboot and show no battery animation.

Comment: Are you tying this device into another device? Update your original question to include the full scope of your issue and delete this answer.

Comment: There's no sense on deleting it since this is the animation file for these asian branded tablets. This is the correct answer. Now i'm running on another issue, that it *might have another file generating the battery animation* somewhere and I need to find it. It's working now, but unfortunately not the best way.

Comment: What NTC stands for?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have adb access as root while in recovery, you can adb pull the *.rc files from recovery's ramdisk and search the entry or similar to

```
on charger
```

to see what the equivalent service is.
Or ,again, while in adb shell in recovery,

```
cat /init.rc
```

which is where the entry for charger/on charger functions should be.
The battery animation resources will be in `/data/media` OR (while in recovery) `/res/images/`

As to the boot on charger plugin, if you don't have your own approach sorted see [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117227/android-tablet-kiosk-development/117231#117231) to a similar question.

Look for the service under the `on charger` section that runs as per on charger, Using the Samsung example, reassign lpm service under on charger as reboot, You can't achieve an instant boot up on plugin, it just doesn't work, so you tell the device that on being plugged in it will reboot to normal operation INSTEAD of beginning it's on charger defined service.
Here is the Samsung example;

From,

```
service lpm /system/bin/lpm
    class charger
    critical
```

To,

```
service lpm /system/bin/reboot
    class charger
    critical
```

Find the equivalent service for your device and make that modification.
Redefining service classes can lead you into a minefield of problems.
Or you just won't boot. You do need to be rooted and so be able to dump,unpack,modify,repack and, rewrite your boot.img

Comment: The changes you are proposing are working just as I answered.

Comment: Aren't there any other solution instead of editing `init.rc`?